# Evenly truncate an array to a given length limit in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I got an array which is longer than the constant integer `limit`. I need to truncate the array to the length `limit`. But later, the array will contain the points of a line diagram. And if I got a lot of points, that can't even be displayed in a browser, I want to "downscale" that data. Thus I want to only remove entries of the data in an equally spreaded sequence.

I tried this:

```java
final Object[] array = /* some array */;
final List<Object> result = * some list */;
final int limit = /* some limit; but suppose that array.length > limit */
final double r = (array.length - limit) / (double) array.length;
double m = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (m >= 1) {
        m -= 1;
    }
    m += r;
    if (m < 1) {
        result.add(array[i]);
    }
}
```

The question is: Will the result always have a length of exactly `limit` and why/why not?

Comment: what does `m%=1` do ??

Comment: So say you have an array with size 50 and the limit is 15, you want to have a List with size 15 containing the first 15 items from the array?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElkady It is the same as `m = m % 1`. It is the modulo operator.

Comment: Why not simply `final List<Object> result = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.copyOf(array, limit));` ?

Comment: is your limit not = 0 or null because you never declare a size?

Comment: I know I mean what is it's functionality in your code , in other word , what do you want to do with it ?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Do you realise that `m % 1` always returns 0?

Comment: This snippet is full of errors.  `array` is final but never assigned.  `m`, an integer, is added to a double, which is pretty questionable.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElkady Please view the update. Sorry.

Comment: you can't use modulo on a double it requires an integer

Comment: Oh, sorry. Let me fix that.

Comment: This code makes no sense. And basically, it will add all of the array to `result`, because `m` is never going to be greater than `1`.

Comment: I think @assylias has the best solution

Comment: Let's say you have 5 points (1,2,3,4,5) but only want to keep 2 points - is it ok to keep 1 and 3 for example? or does it have to be 1 and 5?

Comment: @assylias That would be ok, as long as the removed items are spreaded as evenly as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do the job:

```
public static <T> List<T> limitArray(T[] array, int limit) {
    if (limit > array.length) {
        return Arrays.asList(array);
    }
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    double stepSize = ((double) array.length - 1) / ((double) limit - 1);
    double i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        list.add(array[(int) i]);
        i += stepSize;
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Why `array.length - 1` and `limit - 1`?**
Because the first and the last elements are always added, and the remaining will be divided evenly.
Since you said that *"the array will contain the points of a line diagram"*, I think that it is best to preserve the first and last element, to maintain the full width of the diagram.

Due to the finite precision `double`s as the result of divisions, the array can have one element too few. In that case, this is a possible solution:

- Replace `list.add(array[(int) i])` with `list.add(array[(int) Math.round(i)])`. Note that doing so also affects the other indices of the array being added to our list.

---

**Old answer:**
Why don't you just do this?:

```
public <T> List<T> limitArray(T[] array, int limit) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arrary.length && i < limit) {
        list.add(array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: @assylias: Did you see the edit that the OP made? It actually *was* what was being asked.

Comment: @MCEmperor Why the `array.length-1`?

Comment: @MCEmperor Hmm, and why is the last one always added? And why `i <= array.length`? If `i` becomes `array.length` it would throw an Exception, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock My bad; see edit. I replaced `<=` with `<`. Now `i` can never be greater than `array.length - 1`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank you :) But I still don't understand why the last element of the input array is always added to the final result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68767/discussion-between-mc-emperor-and-minecraftshamrock).

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to keep summing doubles, as you may have glitches due to rounding errors. Building upon MC Emperor's answer:

```
public <T> List<T> limitArray(T[] array, int limit) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    int i = 0;
    double scale = array.length * 1.0/limit;
    while (i < limit) {
        list.add(array[(int)(i * scale)]);
        i++;
    }
    return list;
}
```

This guarantees you have evenly spread items and that you have `limit` items. The `*1.0` is to coerce to double.

Comment: Wow! That is a great solution! Thank you :)

Comment: you need to cast `i * scale` to an integer if you want the code to compile.